# Keep transparancy when reversing video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I need to reverse a video and keep the alpha channel. ffmpeg (version 3.3.4) does a great job, but i just can't figure out how to keep the alpha channel.

Here is the command I execute:

```
ffmpeg -i curtain.webm -vf reverse reversed.webm
```

According to the what I found on the Internet the reverse filter should NOT change anything about quality and should only reverse the frames, but the resulting file is smaller than the original.

---

As asked in the comments, here the full console output:

```
ffmpeg -i curtain.webm -vcodec vp9 -vf reverse curtain_retry.webm
ffmpeg version 3.3.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter
 --enable-avresample --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus
 --enable-libtheora --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopenjpeg
 --enable-libmodplug --enable-libvpx --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex 
 --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-lzma --enable-gnutls
 --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --disable-libxcb
 --disable-libxcb-shm --disable-libxcb-xfixes --disable-indev=jack
 --disable-outdev=xv --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-sdl2
 --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads
 --cc=/usr/bin/clang --enable-vda --enable-videotoolbox --arch=x86_64
 --enable-yasm --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libx264
 --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'curtain.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:00:04.37, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 976 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp9 (native) -> vp9 (libvpx-vp9))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x7fab4800d200] v1.6.1
Output #0, webm, to 'curtain_retry.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (libvpx-vp9), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libvpx-vp9
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    frame=  131 fps=2.7 q=0.0 Lsize=      94kB time=00:00:04.33 bitrate= 177.4kbits/s speed=0.0909x    
    video:92kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.486628%
```

Comment: Share the full console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution.

Short Version:

```
ffmpeg -i original.mov -vcodec qtrle -vf reverse reversed.mov
```

After that it was no problem to convert `reversed.mov` to a `.webm` file with transparency.

---

Longer Version:

I also tried the command with the source version of the file (.mov, codec is Apple Quicktime RLE Video, 606.4MB) and the resulting file was by far smaller and had a different encoding (H264, 594KB). So it had definitely something todo with ffmpeg choosing a default encoding for my output file ending that doesn't support transparency. So I looked up RLE in `ffmpeg -codecs` and set it as explicit codec.

I still don't get why the transparency gets lost when reversing the `.webm` file since both input and output have the same encoding (VP9). I tried setting the codec explicitly but that didn't really change anything about the transparency getting lost.

Comment: thanks for "-vcodec qtrle", this kept the transparency for me